# Create a JSON array from MySQL result array for jQuery datatables

Tags: php, json, codeigniter

I have a mySQL result array in the form such as. If the array is say "$getSessionList"

```
Array(

[0] =>array(

     [name] => azure

          )
[1] =>array(

     [name] => maroon

          )
)
```

My objective is to convert this array into JSON array of this format:

```
{"data": [["azure"],["maroon"]]}
```

I have used this PHP code to get the result:

```
$tableData = new stdClass();
$tableData->data = array();

if (count($getSessionList) > 0) {

for ($i = 0; $i < count($getSessionList); $i ++) {
    $getSessionListRecord = $getSessionList[$i];

    $data = new stdClass(); 
    $data->name   = $getSessionListRecord['name'];


    array_push($tableData->data, $data);

     }
}

echo json_encode($tableData);

?>
```

The above code yields the following result:

```
{"data": [["name":"azure"],["name":"maroon"]]}
```

I want this JSON format array:

```
{"data": [["azure"],["maroon"]]}
```

But my current code is giving me this JSON array:

```
{"data": [["name":"azure"],["name":"maroon"]]}
```

I don't want the keys "name" in the JSON array.

How can I achieve this, any help here will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
$tableData = array();
$tableData['data'] = array_map(function($session) {
    // it's a separate session item inside the session_list
    return array($session['name']);
}, $getSessionList);

// any associative array converts to js-object
// it doesn't matter is that an associative array or std-object
echo json_encode($tableData);
```

Comment: Works great. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this:

```
$tableData = new stdClass();
$tableData->data = array();

if (count($getSessionList) > 0) {

for ($i = 0; $i < count($getSessionList); $i ++) {
    $getSessionListRecord = $getSessionList[$i];

    $data = array($getSessionListRecord['name']);


    array_push($tableData->data, $data);

     }
}

echo json_encode($tableData);

?>
```

Currently you're creating a new PHP object with this code

`$data = new stdClass();`

And then you're adding the data to the key *name* with this line:

`$data->name   = $getSessionListRecord['name'];`

By simply putting the data into an empty array, and pushing that onto your other array you won't have the *name* key when you convert to JSON.

Comment: This solution works perfectly. However @Wizard solution has less LOC so I would prefer it.

Comment: @echology no worries; sometimes people prefer their original code as much as possible because it makes sense to them - hence i kept as much of yours as possible. Glad you got it working!

Comment: I forgot to say thank you. And I must agree as you answered as I had asked. Everybody loves shorthand and especially in programming we sometimes do not know that there are predefined "Methods" which if we would call with parameters will yield us the same result as our many lines of code. So we are the sailors of the same ship in this question :-)